# How to use Jenkins environment variables within Cygwin shell script?

Tags: jenkins, cygwin

We are running a Shell Script in CygWin bash invoked from Jenkins Execute Shell step. Is there a way to access Jenkins Environment variables within the CygWin Shell script?

Comment: I think that `$<variable name>` will work

Comment: In shell script, you can access below Jenkins environment variables,
<Jenkins-Instance>/env-vars.html/

As Rik has mentioned, you can access these variables in script with $<variable name>